# How to use Cabinet (CAB) Files to compress/uncompress a single file in Windows XP/Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, cab

I want to compress/uncompress a single file in my C++ application without using an external library. I have read that Cabinet Files can be used to do this, but I am unable to find any useful examples.

I am not even sure if Cabinet Files can still be used in modern Windows versions, can anyone provide a simple example to do so.

Comment: See [File Compression and Decompression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219.aspx). CAB-files are still supported, because there is no replacement to compress files built into Windows (or at least exposed as an API).

Comment: Not sure why you would not want to use zlib for instance. What's wrong with libraries?

Comment: @David Heffernan What I mean is if Windows API provides this functionality, then why would I use a library.

Comment: To get better compression

Comment: @David Heffernan Good point! but in my case I only want a "normal" compression (the one that you get with the default settings for WinZip/WinRAR), which I've read that Cabinet Files provide.

Comment: I don't know where you read that, but it isn't true. There's no such thing as "normal" compression. There are lots of different algos. ZIP is a container format that can use different algos. Likewise MS cabinet.

Comment: @David Heffernan I assumed that the **LZX** compression algorithm (which Cabinet Files support) provides a "normal" compression ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They still work (Windows 2000 - Windows 10, at least).

See [MSDN for the API Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797921(v=vs.85).aspx) and samples of [how to decompress a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797927(v=vs.85).aspx) or [create a new cabinet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797926(v=vs.85).aspx).

Example implementations for the callbacks are available on their respective pages.  Ex: [`fnMemFree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797945(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`fnNotify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797944(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Is there a separate SDK for Cabinet Files that I should install? because some header files used in the examples are not found. I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: No.  Just `fdi.h`.  You do have to implement the callbacks yourself, as it looks like those are not included in the sample, but they are mostly trivial.

Comment: On review, it looks like the callbacks are available, they are just on their own pages.  I added links to the answer.

Comment: What's missing from the documentation, though, is the calling convention. The Cabinet API uses `__cdecl`. So as a shortcut you could pass `free` or `malloc` directly to `FCICreate`, instead of implementing your own wrappers.